# How to use keyCodeToString() in Android

Tags: android

I want to convert keycode to its symbolic name . i.e. KEYCODE_A . A keycode is 29. In y code, onKeyDown(), when I press key 'A', I want to display what I pressed is 'A', not only the keycode '29'. I look up in developer.android.com, I found there is a way  keyCodeToString(), it seems can do that. Any ideas how to use it?

Thanks a lot.
Best,
Qin

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that keyCodeToString() is what you want. This will return "KEYCODE_A", when A is pressed. Perhaps you want to try [getNumber](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getNumber%28%29) or [getUnicodeChar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar%28%29).

Since keyCodeToString is a static method, you can use it like this:

```
String keyCodeStr = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode);
```

Comment: KEYCODE_A is ok. User can recognize the key by that string instead of keycode '29'. Do you know how to use keyCodeToString()? or is there other way to convert keycode to string? Thanks.